# Nivo slider display issue in IE

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I'm using nivo slider for an image slideshow. All looks good in FF, Chrome etc. It is displaying very strangely in IE though (see attached) (tested on 8(xp) + 9(win7)).

Has anyone come across this before?

Here's the code:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">

                    <img src="pathtoimage" alt="" />
                            <img src="pathtoimage" alt="" />
                       <img src="pathtoimage" alt="" />
                            <img src="pathtoimage" alt="" />

            </div>
        </div>
```

.

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
            effect: 'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
            slices: 15, // For slice animations
            boxCols: 8, // For box animations
            boxRows: 4, // For box animations
            animSpeed: 500, // Slide transition speed
            pauseTime: 3000, // How long each slide will show
            startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
            directionNav: false, // Next & Prev navigation
            directionNavHide: true, // Only show on hover
            controlNav: true, // 1,2,3... navigation
            controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
            pauseOnHover: true, // Stop animation while hovering
            manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
            prevText: 'Prev', // Prev directionNav text
            nextText: 'Next', // Next directionNav text
            randomStart: true, // Start on a random slide
            beforeChange: function(){}, // Triggers before a slide transition
            afterChange: function(){}, // Triggers after a slide transition
            slideshowEnd: function(){}, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
            lastSlide: function(){}, // Triggers when last slide is shown
            afterLoad: function(){} // Triggers when slider has loaded
        });
```

.

```
#slider { height: 309px; }
    .nivoSlider {position:relative; background:url(../thirdparty/nivo-slider/themes/bar/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%; width:640px; height: 309px; box-shadow: none !important; float: left}
    .nivoSlider img {position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; display:none;}
    .nivoSlider a {border:0; display:block;
    }

    .sliderSurround{position: relative; width: 640px; height: 309px;}
    .nivo-controlNav{position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; z-index: 999;}
        .nivo-control{background-image: none !important; background-color: #E00019 !important; cursor: pointer;}
        .nivo-control.active{background-color: #fff !Important}
        .theme-default .nivo-controlNav a{height: 16px !important; width: 16px; margin:0 4px;}
        .theme-default .nivo-controlNav{padding: 15px 10px !important}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's all running from my local ATM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed that the number of repeating image sections (15) correlated with the default "slices" setting in. I changed it to 1 and it solved the issue.

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
            effect: 'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
            slices: 1 // For slice animations
});
```

Comment: This fixed the sticky slices, but the fade effect stopped working :(

Answer (score 2):

I know it's pretty basic, but did you by any chance try one of the themes? All the small, IE specific fixes are in `nivo-slider.css`, the main css, and if you want a theme you also have to add the theme's css. I had the same symptoms, and that was my answer ^_^

So, to be clear, if you went with one of the themes, you css link rels should look like this:

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/nivo-slider.css"

link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="/css/nivo-slider-themes/default/default.css"
```

(fixing this may also make the caption box "appear" in Chrome and FF)