# jquery Nivo slider with Internet explorer

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, nivo-slider

I've got a jquery problem with good old Internet Explorer (I've tested it in IE7, IE8 and IE9 and they all produce the same problem). I'm using the Nivo Slider plugin for a website. Only in IE it goes wrong. Somehow the image duplicates itself and pastes it next to each other (I am sorry for my bad English, you can see the problem below on the pictures).

How the image in the slider should look like:
[image]

How the image in the slider looks like in Internet Explorer:
[image]

You can find my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/YszGW/10/

This is my Nivo Slider configuration:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#photoSlider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'fade',
        animSpeed: 1000,
        pauseTime: 5000,
        directionNav: true,
        controlNav: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        randomStart: true
});
});
```

I have no idea where to look. I don't know if it is a javascript problem or a css problem. Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, please use jsFiddle properly; paying attention to the panel on the far left.  http://jsfiddle.net/YszGW/11/

Comment: I noticed that the CSS in your jsFiddle demo is missing the default CSS file that is normally included with Nivo.  The CSS you manually entered seemed to be heavily trimmed down from the default Nivo CSS.  In my experience, leaving out the default CSS always seems to cause strange issues with many of these jQuery slider plugins.  Put back **all** of the default CSS for Nivo and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:  @Sparky pointed out that my answer didn't help because you're experiencing problems in all versions of IE, in which case the trailing comma fix wouldn't help.  My apologies.

However, I found some users that had the same problem you did.  It looks like specifying `slices: 1` instead of leaving it as default seems to fix it.  Thread referenced below.

[Nivo slider display issue in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839842/nivo-slider-display-issue-in-ie)

EDIT2: Sparky made another good point in the comments below.  Even if changing the slices 'fixes' the issue, it doesn't mean it got rid of the original problem.  Nivo slider comes with CSS that will make sure it looks and functions well in different browsers, so if you removed those it could definitely cause these problems.  I would try putting back in the default CSS first to make sure you're using the plugin as the devs intended.

If that doesn't work hopefully the slices fix takes care of it for you though.

Comment: I followed your [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558920/nivo-slider-not-working-with-ie7) and then followed the [link](http://support.dev7studios.com/discussions/general-discussion/42-nivo-slider-dissapearing-in-ie7-8-after-loading) in your link.  That just seems like a "trailing comma of death" issue, which would only affect IE 7 (also as indicated in your link).  The OP is having problems in **all versions** of IE... can you provide any documentation to support that?

Comment: You're right, it was a trailing comma of death problem that I had referenced and that wouldn't help.  There are still others with the same problem though and it seems they fixed it.  See edit.

Comment: Looking at [the code](http://poplight.hpu.nl/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js), there is no default setting for `slices`, so not really sure how `slices: 1` solves anything when the OP is not using that option in the first place.  I, like many others, have managed to use Nivo without any IE issues, so there is something the OP is doing wrong.

Comment: Line 637 `$.fn.nivoSlider.defaults`.  Slices default is set at 15.

Comment: Yes, I missed that.  However, please explain how thousands of websites use Nivo without this issue.  Perhaps, because the OP removed most of the default CSS that shipped with Nivo?

Comment: I've used Nivo slider on lots of projects myself and have never had a problem with it on any browsers either(that's why I like it so much).  Not sure why it would have a problem now, but my guess is that you're right about OP removing default CSS.  I would bet that putting back the default CSS would fix it just fine without having to use unintended hacks.

Comment: Thank you guys, the problem is solved. A colleague made some changes in the nivo slider CSS file that I was not aware of (he forgot it too :S ). I put back the original CSS file and know it works like a charme, even in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same. I've read on the net that adding "height: auto;" to ".nivoslider img" would work, but for me it didn't. 
Strangely what did work in IE was the following setting:

$('#idOfSlider').nivoSlider({ 
slices: 1, 
...,
randomStart: true, 
... 
});

The combination of 1 slice (and of course there are more in your code) with randomStart did the trick.